# Java initializing abstract classes

Tags: java, initialization, abstract-class

Can someone explain this line of code for me?

`SomeAbstractClass variable = new SomeAbstractClass() { };`

This properly instantiaties and stores the abstract instance in the variable. What is happening? An anonymous class that extends the abstract class, maybe? Any keywords I can use to look up information about this? (the abstract class also happens to be generic if that has any relevance)

Comment: The keywords in your question are anonymous and extends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line above is creating an anonymous subclass of `SomeAbstractClass`, which will not be `abstract`. Of course, this will work only if the base class has no `abstract` methods to implement.

Actually, I cannot visualize an useful instance (besides "documentation" features, see the comment below) of the line above, unless you are implementing  and/or overriding methods between curly braces. That is a quite common technique if the base class/interface happens to have few methods to implement and the implementation is simple. You can even refer to the `final` variables of the surrounding method and parameters, thus making a closure.

Comment: I have seen it in mock objects in unit tests, where the real application should always use derived classes. `abstract` in that case would be more a documentation feature and a warning to avoid creating instances of the base class rather than necessary for the implementation.

Comment: @kiheru nice. I have added a pointer to your comment in the answer.

Comment: To refer to the variables in the surrounding method, they need to be `final` as well. And even if they are, the anonymous inner class only *effectively* makes a closure. It isn't really a closure.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous class which is a subclass of your `abstract` class.  Like was pointed out in comments, you are looking at an anonymous extends.

Something like follows would work if you had `abstract` methods to implement:

```
MyAbstractClass someObjectOfThatClass = new MyAbstractClass(){
                       @Override
                       public void someAbstractMethod(){

                       }
                    }
```

You can do the same with interfaces as they can also contain `abstract` methods. A practical example would be adding an `ActionListener` to a `JButton`:

```
myJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    // code
                }
            });
```

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I thought a little bit of humor would work

Answer (score 1):

Java gives you the ability to create anonymous subclasses inline. You often see this in the context of anonymous inner classes with Swing event handling, but there are many other applications as well.

In your example, you are creating a class that extends `SomeAbstractClass` anonymously and assigning it to a `SomeAbstractClass` reference. It would be just as if you created a separate class like this

```
public class SomeConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractClass {
}
```

and later did this

```
SomeAbstractClass variable = new SomeConcreteClass();
```

As noted by @Stefano, your approach only works if your anonymous concrete class has no abstract methods, which would be true because `SomeAbstractClass` has no abstract methods.